# Regex: capture between starting delimiter and optional ending delimiter

Tags: javascript, regex

With the following string:

```
foo/:something/bar/:somethingelse
```

How can I capture `something` and `somethingelse` considering the optional `/` ending delimiter on the second case?

Using `(?<=:)(.*?)(?=\/)` only returns `something`, which makes sense.

So I've tried `(?<=:)(.*?)(?=\/|$)` but it doesn't return `somethingelse` either.

According to Regex101 this `(?=\/|$)` means either `/` or end of the string, so in principle `somethingelse` should be captured.

https://regex101.com/r/gU4uR9/2

What am I missing?

Comment: There are no lookbehinds in JS.

Comment: Ok... so how can I solve this?

Comment: Why not use string manipulation instead of regex? You could split by `/` and find the strings that start with `:`

Comment: Yes, that was my initial "brute force" approach, but I thought regex would be more elegant. I hope someone can answer this though.

Comment: Perhaps you could make more clear by what logic `foo/` should not be captured, but `somethingelse` should. In particular since you wrote that `somethingelse` could also end with a slash.

Comment: You missed `g`. This `/(?:\:)(.*?)(?=\/|$)/g` captures what you want

Comment: Thanks @AlexKudryashev but I wasn't using the proper regex format as JS doesn't support lookbehinds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already pointed out by others, the JavaScript regex engine is somewhat crippled (and does not support lookbehinds).
The usual work-around is to **match** the things before (this *consumes* characters) and **capture** the desired substring in a group afterwards:

```
\/:([^/]+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/cD4tL2/1).

In `JS` code, this would be:

```
var str = "foo/:something/bar/:somethingelse";
var re = /\/:([^/]+)/g;
var matches = str.match(re);
```

Thanks to @Wiktor for the clarification of nomenclature.

Comment: *Match in a group* means *capture*. We match what we do not need and capture what we want to obtain.