# Understanding positive look behind regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I was just reading [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172232/regex-capture-between-starting-delimiter-and-optional-ending-delimiter) and came across the following regex:

```
(?<=:)(.*?)(?=\/|$)
```

I would like to know what exactly this piece of regex is doing `(?<=:)`.

If I check the regex on regex101.com I get the following:

> (?<=: ) Positive Lookbehind - Assert that the regex below can be
> matched : matches the character : literally.

Now that's I am just learning regexs and I understand that if I have something like the following:

```
(?:car)
```

it basically means a non capturing group, but now what does (`?<=:`) mean? In what way is this useful?

Comment: Look behinds are not supported in Javascript!

Comment: There are [**no lookbehinds in JavaScript**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172232/regex-capture-between-starting-delimiter-and-optional-ending-delimiter/38172462#38172462).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:** First thing first. ***<s>Lookbehinds are not supported in Javascript.</s>***

**[Apr 23, 2018]** Lookbehinds are now supported in Javascript. See the proposal [**`here`**](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind).

**Explanation of lookbehinds**

I will give an analogy to explain this. Suppose you are standing at some place facing front side. Now you want to see what is behind you.

**So what do you do?**

You move your head (*probably entire body by 180 degree*) backwards ***without changing your position*** and observe what is there.

This is *somewhat* lookbehind similar to.

> You are currently at some position of text you are matching (*this is like facing forward direction*) and you want to see what is behind.
>
> Lookbehind is zero width means it does not consume any string which is similar to **you want to see what is behind without changing your position**

So using the regex `(?<=:)abc`, you are basically trying to find all positions of `abc` where there is a `:` just before `abc`.

Remember `:` is just checked and is not stored anywhere because of `zero-width` assertion property of `look(aheads|behinds)`

**NOTE**

This was just a loosely coupled analogy for better understanding and visualization. In reality at every position the existence of `:` is checked backwards, like for string `ab:abc` (*spaces below are for clarity*)

```
a b : a b c
 ^
When this is the position of checking, a is matched with :

a b : a b c
   ^
When this is the position of checking, b is matched with :

a b : a b c
     ^ 
When this is the position of checking, : is matched with :
As they match, now abc of regex is matched against string abc.
If successful match is found.
```

**NOTE 1**

Most of the regex library of programming languages do not supports variable/infinte width lookbehind except few like `.NET`, `regex` library of python etc. So using `(?<=:*)` etc. will give an error.

Comment: I like the analogy (+1) :)

Comment: You might want to add, that most regex flavours don't support infinite width lookbehinds, contrary to lookaheads.

Comment: @rock321987 well thanks now i kind of understand the importance of positive look behinds .. so PHP does support positive lookbehinds but JS does't  right ? https://regex101.com/r/lT8gR3/1 .

Answer (score 1):

`Positive lookbehind` will match only if what is inside the `positive lookbehind` group match.
You are right that in most scenario, using a `non capturing group` will behave the same.

But there is a difference:

- [`/(?:foo)bar/`](https://regex101.com/r/mX3bA0/2) will capture `foobar`
- [`/(?<=foo)bar/`](https://regex101.com/r/mX3bA0/1) will only capture `bar` (if precede by `foo`)

Answer (score 1):

Lookbehind is not supported in Javascript.

Basically, lookbehind is used to verify that something can be matched - but it will not be added to the final result. So, for example, if you want to match abc, surrounded by numbers, but you just want the abc, and your regex flavor supports lookarounds you can write something like: `(?<=[0-9])(abc)(?=[0-9])` . This would mean: "I want abc, but only when it is following and preceding a number."

In the example in your question, it means: "Match everything between `:` and `/`"

Comment: Just as a side note: Most regex flavours support fixed width lookbehinds, while only very few support infinte width lookbehinds (.net does). So `(?<=[0-9]+)` will be invalid in most (PCRE, Java, Boost), while `(?<=[0-9])` would be OK.

Comment: Oops, sorry. My bad.